# convert JSON to data.frame in R

Tags: json, r, dataframe

I have problem with converting lists to data.frame

First I have downloaded dataset in JSON format from Data API:

```
request1 <- POST(url = "https://api.data-api.io/v1/subjekti", add_headers('x-dataapi-key' = "xxxxxxx", 'content-type'= "application/json"), body = list(oib = oibreq), encode = "json")
json1 <- content(request1, type = "application/json")
json2 <- fromJSON(toJSON(json1, null = "null"), flatten = TRUE)
```

The problem is that data are elements of lists. For example

```
> json2[['oib']]
[[1]]
[1] "00045103869"

[[2]]
[1] "18527887472"

[[3]]
[1] "92680516748"
```

all colnames:

```
> colnames(json2)
 [1] "oib"               "mb"                "mbs"               "mbo"               "rno"               "naziv"            
 [7] "adresa"            "grad"              "posta"             "zupanija"          "nkd2007"           "puo"              
[13] "godinaOsnivanja"   "status"            "temeljniKapital"   "isActive"          "datumBrisanja"     "predmetPoslovanja"
```

How can I convert this lists to data.frame?

Sorry, that was my first question on stockoverflow. There is my dataset:

```
> data <- dput(json3)
structure(list(oib = list("00045103869", "18527887472", "92680516748"), 
    mb = list("01699032", "03858731", "02591596"), mbs = list(
        "080451345", "060060881", "040260786"), mbo = c(NA, NA, 
    NA), rno = c(NA, NA, NA), naziv = list("INTERIJER DIZAJN d.o.o.", 
        "M - Đ COMMERCE d.o.o.", "HIP REKLAME d.o.o. u stečaju"), 
    adresa = list("Savska cesta 179", "Put Piketa 0", "Sadska 2"), 
    grad = list("Zagreb", "Sinj", "Rijeka"), posta = list("10000", 
        "21230", "51000"), zupanija = list("Grad Zagreb", "Splitsko-dalmatinska", 
        "Primorsko-goranska"), nkd2007 = list("1623", "4719", 
        "4711"), puo = list(92L, 92L, 92L), godinaOsnivanja = list(
        "2003", "1995", "2009"), status = list("bez postupka", 
        "bez postupka", "stečaj"), temeljniKapital = list("20.000,00 kn", 
        "509.100,00 kn", "20.000,00 kn"), isActive = list(TRUE, 
        TRUE, FALSE), datumBrisanja = list(NULL, NULL, "2015-12-24T00:00:00+01:00")), .Names = c("oib", 
"mb", "mbs", "mbo", "rno", "naziv", "adresa", "grad", "posta", 
"zupanija", "nkd2007", "puo", "godinaOsnivanja", "status", "temeljniKapital", 
"isActive", "datumBrisanja"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
3L))
```

Comment: how is 'oibreq' defined?

Comment: #1 Please provide a [reproducible example](https://www.google.com/search?q=r+reproducible+example), not just some random excerpts of your data. #2 Check out e.g. `json2 <- list(oib=as.list(1:3)); json2[['oib']]; as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, json2))`.

Comment: lukeA, unfortunately, your code doesn't do job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick & dirty way would be to substitute the `NULL` values by e.g. `NA`s like this

```
f <- function(lst) lapply(lst, function(x) if (is.list(x)) f(x) else if (is.null(x)) NA_character_ else x)
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(f(json2), unlist))
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  17 variables:
#  $ oib            : Factor w/ 3 levels "00045103869",..: 1 2 3
#  $ mb             : Factor w/ 3 levels "01699032","02591596",..: 1 3 2
#  $ mbs            : Factor w/ 3 levels "040260786","060060881",..: 3 2 1
#  $ mbo            : logi  NA NA NA
#  $ rno            : logi  NA NA NA
#  $ naziv          : Factor w/ 3 levels "HIP REKLAME d.o.o. u stecaju",..: 2 3 1
#  $ adresa         : Factor w/ 3 levels "Put Piketa 0",..: 3 1 2
#  $ grad           : Factor w/ 3 levels "Rijeka","Sinj",..: 3 2 1
#  $ posta          : Factor w/ 3 levels "10000","21230",..: 1 2 3
#  $ zupanija       : Factor w/ 3 levels "Grad Zagreb",..: 1 3 2
#  $ nkd2007        : Factor w/ 3 levels "1623","4711",..: 1 3 2
#  $ puo            : int  92 92 92
#  $ godinaOsnivanja: Factor w/ 3 levels "1995","2003",..: 2 1 3
#  $ status         : Factor w/ 2 levels "bez postupka",..: 1 1 2
#  $ temeljniKapital: Factor w/ 2 levels "20.000,00 kn",..: 1 2 1
#  $ isActive       : logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE
#  $ datumBrisanja  : Factor w/ 1 level "2015-12-24T00:00:00+01:00": NA NA 1
```

But there may be better options.

Comment: lukeA, your code solves my problem! I am only confused about levels. Is it possible to remove levels somehow? Maybe I should add as.Factor = FALSE. somewhere in the code?

Comment: You could try`as.data.frame(lapply(f(json2), unlist), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`.